# Javascript get session cookie from the server

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a quick way to easily open the *Advanced Search* tab of a library search engine via bookmark. In order to open the tab, I need to send a form including a hidden input to enable advanced functionalities, however sometimes I get a

> session mismatch error

despite sending a session cookie alongside.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Advanced Search</title>
        <script>
            function getToPost()
            {
                // Set session cookie
                document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=CBE2D2A4FF8F33A2748299LP825BB023";
                sessionStorage.setItem("JSESSIONID", "CBE2D2A4FF8F33A2748299LP825BB023");

                // Send form
                var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
                form.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                form.action = 'https://www.url.com';
                var element1=document.createElement("input");
                element1.value="Advanced Search";
                element1.name="searchadv";
                form.appendChild(element1);
                form.submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="getToPost()">
        <form method="POST"></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

A possible alternative would be to grab the session cookie first and then send the form, how can I do it with JavaScript?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are acctually trying to do a [CSRF attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). If the target website is well prepared for CSRF attacks, you are not able to "find a quick way to easily open the Advanced Search tab".

Comment: the website does not require authentication, no login is needed

Comment: @Anelito Even if the website is not intented to authenticate, you may be still stoped  from doing so by the safety mechanism for CSRF of webstie and browser.